# Why Javascript Array#shift or Array#slice cause a performance issues?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I've been resolving [a hacker rank problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/array-left-rotation). The idea it's move "to the left" the elements at first index n times. The problem is when my algorithm receives a large arrays. Produces in the Hacker Rank server a timeout problem. I don't understand the issues behind this problem. 
**Anybody knows what happen that?**

I tried two ideas

Example Input

```
5 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

Example output

```
5 1 2 3 4
```

**Idea 1**

```
function processData(input) {
    var input_arguments = input.split(/\n/),
        rotations_count = parseInt(input_arguments[0].split(/\s/)[1],10),
        array = input_arguments[1].split(/\s/);

    while(rotations_count--){
        let value = array[0];
        array = array.slice(1);
        array.push(value);
    }
    console.log(array.join(' '));
}
```

**Idea2**

```
function processData(input) {
    var input_arguments = input.split(/\n/),
        rotations_count = parseInt(input_arguments[0].split(/\s/)[1],10),
        array = input_arguments[1].split(/\s/);

    while(rotations_count > 0){
        array.push(array.shift());
        rotations_count--;
    }
    console.log(array.join(' '));
}
```

Comment: First of all, you've made a typo and used `splice` not `slice`.

Comment: A solution using `slice` or `shift` d times has a complexity of `O(d n)`. You should be able to get this down to `O(n)`. According to the "constraints" given on Hackerrank, this means that in the worst case the bad solution is on the order of 10000 times slower.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. Now the challenge sounds even much interesting! :D

Comment: Hint: don't create a new array at all

Comment: @Bergi actually they could create a new array for holding the result, but just perform a shift as a one time operation

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do the shifts one-by-one, but an efficient solution would do one big shift all-at-once. The "issue" you're missing is that the number of shifts tells you where in the array you can "cut it" into two, and then you can take the first part and add it to the end of the second part. Using their example:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let shifts = 4;

// Create a temp array holding the values of 'array' up the shift point
let temp = array.slice(0, shifts);

// Delete the beginning of 'array' up to shift point
// and add the temp array to the end of 'array'
let newArray = array.splice(shifts).concat(temp);
```

That's all there is to it.

Comment: Right idea, but what if `shifts` is 400? By the way, this code doesn't work. It returns `[5, 5]`. I think you forgot that `splice` returns the deleted elements.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the typo. It should return the correct result now. The size of `shifts` is meaningless with this solution. You're using native methods to cut and concat the arrays all-at-once rather than using a loop to do it one at a time. I've passed the challenge on HackerRank with this exact solution. Maybe there's an even more efficient solution but this one worked for me.

Comment: I don't know what tests HackerRank is using, but a `shifts` of 392 SHOULD work, but DOESN'T with your solution.

Comment: @torazaburo I see what you mean - that is out of the scope of this challenge as there is a constraint on the size of shifts, it must always be less than the size of the array (see the top section of the link). You can't continually "shift-over" the array like you're thinking. It doesn't work for that type of problem because `slice()` is being called from 0 to a number larger than the length of the array.

Comment: I don't see that constraint. Must be missing something.

Comment: @torazaburo You must be, there's a bold section for constraints towards the top of the page: Constraints: 1 <= n <= 10^5, 1 <= d <= n where n is the size of the array and d is the number of left rotations to perform.

Comment: You're right, thanks for clarifying. Minor point, but instead of using both slice and splice, wouldn't something like `[...array.slice(d), ...array.slice(0, d)]` be more semantic?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant `slice` not `splice`